# No sound on Arch Linux (ALSA)

Tags: linux, audio, arch-linux, alsa

**Output of** `aplay -l`

```
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

**output of** sudo `aplay -l`

```
**** *List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices* ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

My sound is unmuted in alsamixer and sudo alsamixer (diffrerent for some reason)

**A Link to my /dev/snd/* output**

> http://ix.io/irz

Anything else needed?

Comment: Is your user member of the `audio` group?

Answer (score 3):

1) Check if the `user` is part of the `audio` group:

```
id <user>
```

If not, add the user to the group with:

```
usermod -aG audio <user>
```

A logout/login will probably be necessary to re-activate

2) If you have a /dev/audio device, try copying any smallish (about 50kB) to that device:

```
cat file > /dev/audio
```

if you hear anything, then audio is working. If you do not have /dev/audio, you might have a bad configuration.

Comment: @AhmedDeq: Please mark the answer as Accepted - clicking on the 'V' to the left of the answer. That makes it easier for other users to find it!